# what is causing border-radius to not work?

Tags: html, css

I've tested this both in Chrome and in Firefox.  I'm attempting to make slight rounded edges on a table of mine, and I don't understand why the `border-radius` command is not working.

Here's the jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hz018pLz/

When I use `CTRL+SHIFT+I` to look at the computed styles, I see that this element has

`border-radius: 20px;` ticked, but unselecting it makes no change to the display of the table.

What am I not doing that I need to be doing in order for this to work?

Here's the code as well:

```css
#bp-table {
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 99%;
  max-width: 99%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#bp-table th {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgb(60, 55, 88);
  color: #ffffff;
}
#bp-table td {
  padding: 8px;
  background: #e8edff;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#bp-table tr:hover td {
  background: #f0d3d3;
  color: #1e1e5b;
}
```

```html
<table id="bp-table">
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please enter the code in your question and not just jsfiddle, so that when/if link-rot occurs, your question will still be valid.

Comment: @HashemQolami I think this answer is more precise than the other on the duplicate ... Mine explain why happens but there on the duplicate is just try this ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The elements inside are still rectangular and full visible so you can change the overflow property to avoid that visual rect :

```
#bp-table {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check the [UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz018pLz/1/)

Comment: I would also suggest using the other prefixes - a [generator](http://border-radius.com/) actually creates them for you (for better cross browser support on older browsers i.e *if you need Firefox 3.6 and lower or iOS 4.3 and Safari 5.0*)

Comment: @jbutler483 border-radius doesn't need prefixes

Comment: It does for super old unused browsers. :P

Comment: Just chekc here http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius and the global use

Comment: He isn't wrong, it does on SUPER OLD browsers.  So it isn't needed anymore as they aren't even used (that is what I was saying): http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: @SimplyCraig about w3schools is just my opinion http://www.w3fools.com/ you can use instead direct w3 or mdn